# Ajax empty data returned

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, jsonp

I am using Angular, but same thing happens with a normal jQuery Ajax request, to get data.

Data structure is:

```
    {
    "providers":
    {
        "complete":[1,2,3],
        "inProgress":[4,5,6]
    },
    "results":
    [
        {"thing":{"id":"1234"},"somethingelse":null},
        {"thing":{"id":"5678"},"somethingelse":null}
    ]
}
```

The Ajax request looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
            url: $resultsURL
        }).done(function(data) {
```

and the Angular request:

```
            $http.jsonp($resultsURL)
                .success(function(data, status){
```

Now, kind of hard to explain without a demo and sadly I can't expose any of the api endpoints, but the above works fine, as expected and tells me I have two results.

Now the real issue, I can append a partials request to the url and get back a smaller data set, with an offset etc, if I try console.log(data.results) I get an empty []. If I try data.results.length, it returns 0.

Appreciate that might not make much sense, so I guess the first thing to solve is why the ajax might return the length of data.results as zero?

Have I missed something massively obvious?

Cheers

Comment: What is the value of `$resultsURL`?

Comment: Along the lines of
var $resultsURL = $settings.api + '/results/' + $scope.enquiryId + '?partialfrom=' + $scope.partialFrom +  '&partiallimit=' + $scope.partialLimit + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools or firebug to see what the response is in the network window?

Comment: yeah it looks fine. When I open the response in a new tab, there are loads of results.

Comment: Well since you can not expose the API, could you take the JSON response and create a plunker or jsfiddle that just makes the JSONP request to a .JSON file containing your response data. Without some example of the issue it will be very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: It works fine when requesting it from a local JSON. Sorry, not sure what else I can do without exposing all the endpoints which I'm not allowed to do. If I find out the solution I'll post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was hitting the service too quickly so it thought it was empty initially.